# runnig python tests via teamcity: Error: Source not found

Tags: python, continuous-integration, teamcity, virtualenv

I want to use teamcity as CI for my python project. My project use virtualenv to store project related dependencies. So I create venv folder under project root and put env. related stuff there.

But when I trying to create build step with `source venv/bin/activate` as custom script - it fails with `source: not found`, if i creating this step also as command line, but executable file and put `source` as file and `venv/bin/activate` as parameter, then it fails with `Cannot run process source venv/bin/activate : file not found`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, solution seem like that

1. implement custom bash scripts like tests.sh
2. create step which execute this files like `bash tests.sh`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.` instead of `source` like this...

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved it by adding `#!/bin/sh` at the beggining. :)

Thank you for your answers as well.